# How to trigger a callback when the user has selected some text and hit Ctrl+C or click copy?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Let's say the user selects some random text on a page and hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> (or <kbd>Cmd+C</kbd> on Mac) or even click "Copy" in the Edit Menu.

How to listen to this event in a Chrome extension with an associated callback?

I couldn't figure it out from the [Google Chrome Extention](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/) docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a Javascript/DOM question than a Chrome Extension question.

Add a event listener for the **copy** event:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(e) { console.log(e); });
```

Comment: This gets me the element with its whole content, not what has been copied. I need this to work as a Chrome Extension to be able to trigger callback whenever I copy something from any page.

Comment: Ok, I got it working starting with your answer and coming back to the chrome docs. Thanks.